# Pandas to_datetime not following format & producing incorrect results

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, lambda, format

I have a dataframe with two columns for time (`BgnDate` and `EndDate`). Currently the format of these columns is `float64`, but I need them in the pandas datetime format. I tried running `pd.to_datetime` with a format of `%Y-%m-%d` but I always get seconds included, which I don't want. In addition, Pandas is computing the column values incorrectly. Below is an example of my input, script, and output:

`BgnDate = 19700907`

```
input_data_df[['BgnDate', 'EndDate']] = input_data_df[['BgnDate', 'EndDate']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce'))
```

`BgnDate = 1970-01-01 00:00:00.019990907`

What I want my output to look like is: '1999-09-07'

^^ Notice that the month and date are incorrect for the output.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: What should the date be? `1970-09-07`?

Comment: Yes, in the format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your format is incorrect. Try `%Y%m%d` instead of `%Y-%m-%d`:

```
df[['BgnDate', 'EndDate']] = df[['BgnDate', 'EndDate']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: But I'd like the dashes to separate each measurement. I believe I have done that before without issue.

Comment: What should `BgnDate = 19700907` evaluate to, then?

Comment: I want the format of: '1979-09-07'

Comment: Have you tried my code? It does that for you.

Comment: Or do you want to keep only the date, and remove the time portion?

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Guess it was just a tiny formatting issue :') Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome! :)